# How to create textview that hold the count of items in recyclerview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have tried to create recyclerview and Textview that hold the number of items inside the recyclerview. When I scroll down the number of item should be increased. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
    Context context;

    TextView Counter;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems){
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        FeedItem current = feedItems.get(position);
        String count = Integer.toString(++position);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " Processing: " + count);

//        Toast toastMessage = Toast.makeText(this, "Text value is now " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//        toastMessage.show();


        holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.Artist.setText(current.getArtist());
        holder.Date.setText(current.getReleaseDate());
        Picasso.with(context).load(current.getImageUrl()).into(holder.Image);


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Title,Artist,Date;
        ImageView Image;

        //TextView ItemsCounter;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
            Artist= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter_text);
            Date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            Image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_img);
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me this is the best I did..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get position of first visible item in your recyclerview from findFirstVisibleItemPosition() method of the recyclerviews' Layout Manager

```
mRecycleView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int positionView = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(positionView)); //The TextView you want to update
     }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I need. It is working fine @Shreyas Ponkshe